# Docker: перезапуск контейнера и расшаренная сеть

Tags: docker, docker-compose

- Есть приложение с docker-compose и в нём есть контейнер (`app_www_1`) с nginx, собственно, отдающим это приложение
- Для приложения создаётся дефолтная локальная сеть `app_default`
- Есть глобальный nginx (тоже в докере), который запросы для определённого виртуального хоста проксирует на `app_www_1`

`docker-compose.yml` для глобального nginx:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

    nginx:
        container_name: global_nginx
        image: nginx:alpine
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        # ...
        networks:
            - app_default
            # ...
        external_links:
            - app_www_1
            # ...

networks:
    app_default:
        external: true
    # ...
```

В `nginx.conf`, соответственно, `proxy_pass http://app_www_1;`

**Вопрос 1:** правильно ли здесь организован проброс запросов?

Всё работает как надо, но не получается перезапустить приложение (`docker-compose stop` + `up -d`):

```
error while removing network: network app_default id ... has active endpoints
```

То есть сетка занята "глобальным" контейнером.
После поднятия приложения для него создаётся новая сетка и они теперь друг друга не видят.
Приходится останавливать global_nginx, перезапускать app, запускать снова global_nginx, тогда работает.

**Вопрос 2:** как это решить, чтобы не останавливать каждый раз глобальный контейнер?

Comment: Это вы вчера задавали подобный вопрос? Тогда у вас был один глобальный nginx, плюс несколько docker-compose под каждое приложение. В том случае можно было создать одну общую сеть, которая объединит все вместе (`docker network create ...`, `docker network connect ...`), вот [пример как это сделать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40333622/9435985).

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо за ответ. Общая сеть меня смущает тем, что, во-первых, все приложения хоста попадут в единую сеть, а во-вторых, приложениям придётся знать о своём окружении, о том, что на хосте есть такая сеть с таким-то названием. Моё решение, в принципе, работает, единственное смущает, ошибка при дауне приложения.

Comment: `ошибка при дауне приложения.` - пробуйте `docker-compose stop --remove-orphans`. `Приходится останавливать global_nginx, перезапускать app, запускать снова global_nginx, тогда работает.` - напишите скрипт автоматизрующий это все. Или цепляйте через `docker network connect ...` ваше приложение к nginx-сети, тогда перезапуск nginx не нужен. Или вариант с пробросом кучи портов - как вы делали прошлый раз. Вариант нормальный, только закройте эти порты от интернета.